# Obtener la URL del ultimo archivo subido a mi drive

Tags: java, android-studio, google-api, google-drive

estoy trabajando con Android Studio y JAVA, lo que hago es generar un PDF que se sube a mi drive, y de este drive genero un QR que abrirá el archivo, mi problema es que necesito obtener la URL del ultimo archivo subido, he intentado esto pero me sale que es codigo obsoleto, estoy usando esta api com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0', este es mi codigo

public String getLastUploadedFileUrl () {

```
// Get the Drive API client.
DriveClient driveClient = new DriveClient(this);

// Create a query to list all files.
Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .build();

// Get the last file.
Task<MetadataBuffer> queryTask = driveClient.query(query);
queryTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<MetadataBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<MetadataBuffer> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = task.getResult();
            if (metadataBuffer.getItems().size() > 0) {
                // Get the last file.
                Metadata metadata = metadataBuffer.getItems().get(0);
                String lastFileUrl = metadata.getWebContentLink();
                return lastFileUrl;
            }
        } else {
            // Handle error.
        }
    }
});

return queryTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<MetadataBuffer, String>() {
    @Override
    public String then(@NonNull Task<MetadataBuffer> task) throws Exception {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = task.getResult();
            if (metadataBuffer.getItems().size() > 0) {
                // Get the last file.
                Metadata metadata = metadataBuffer.getItems().get(0);
                String lastFileUrl = metadata.getWebContentLink();
                return lastFileUrl;
            }
        } else {
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return null;} }); }
```